# "Growing" mesh in all directions

Tags: mesh, surface-deform

I'm new to blender so excuse me if the question is dumb.

Basically I need to create a model that wraps my original model similar to how varnish adds layers to some physical object. As you add varnish layers to a physical object all its holes will reduce in size while object will become larger and smoother. After some n-th layer all of the holes will become completely sealed by the varnish and if process is continued any object will become more and more similar to a sphere.

Such operation is nothing similar to a regular object scaling.

Are there any tools in Blender capable of achieving such goal or maybe there's other tools that can do the job?

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe you need either the Solidify modifier or you can extrude faces along normals by pressing Alt+N (just select the faces you need to extrude).

Comment: @Tsybe Alt N doesn't technically extrude. It moves vertices without adding geometry.

Comment: I meant Alt+E. I misspelled it, sorry.

Comment: Thank you @Tsybe

Answer (score 1):

I've eventually used the following sequence of actions:

1. Edit mode > Mesh > Transform > Shrink / Flatten
2. Add Modifier > Boolean
3. Set Operand Type to "Collection"
4. Leave collection field empty
5. Apply modifier

Steps from 2 to 5 are necessary to remove internal geometry parts:

**Original:**
[image]

**Result:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays you can get this effect with geometry nodes kinda like this:

[image]